# Showing and Hiding Select Elements Kills Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have two select inputs set to display:none.  Based on `change()` in another element I use jQuery to `show()` or `hide()` them.  All of my browser tests look great except for Chrome which dies with the "Something went wrong..." message.  Here is my function

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supplier_type").change(function () {
      if ($("#supplier_type").val() == 'Wholesaler') {
        $("#retail_fulfillment").hide("slow");
        $("#retail_fulfillment").val("");
        $("#wholesale_fulfillment").show("slow");
      } else {
        if ($("#supplier_type").val() == 'Retailer') {
        $("#wholesale_fulfillment").hide("slow");
        $("#wholesale_fulfillment").val("");
        $("#retail_fulfillment").show("slow");
        }
      }
    });
```

Anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: Have you tried calling it the `hide()` method without parameters?

Comment: Thanks naivists!  Turns out that if I eliminate the args to both show() and hide() the error is eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per naivists' comment above I tried calling hide() with no parameters.  This did not resolve the issue but removing the args from both show() and hide() did resolve Chrome's issue.

Answer (score 1):

`#wholesale_fulfillment` and `#retail_fullfillment` are both select-elements, isn't it? You set the value of a select element to nothing. I guess that's the problem; it's impossible.

This will be your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supplier_type").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Wholesaler') {
            $("#retail_fulfillment").hide("slow")
            //$("#retail_fulfillment").find('option.empty').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $("#wholesale_fulfillment").show("slow");
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Retailer') {
            $("#wholesale_fulfillment").hide("slow");
            //$("#wholesale_fulfillment").find('option.empty').attr('selected', 'selected');
            $("#retail_fulfillment").show("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you still want to select an `<option/>`-tag with an empty value, just add a class to that `<option/>`-tag and uncomment the commented Javascript-code:

```
<select id="#wholesale_fulfillment">
    <option value="" class="empty">---</option>
    <option value="something">Wholesaler</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harmen.  I tried removing the value setting lines outright but Chrome still dies.  Asa further test I commented out the show() and hide() calls and Chrome stopped dying.

Comment: Chrome stopped dying when show() was not called. Commenting out hide() had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone have any advice on this?

Yes. [See if a bug has already been filed for this issue.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

If not, file one. Include a minimal test case; [pastehtml.com](http://pastehtml.com/) is nice for that sort of thing.

And hack around the crash as best you can.